# Узнать ip адрес сервиса itrack.ru/whatcms и запретить определять мой сайт

Tags: ip

Здравствуйте всем!
Хочу узнать ip адрес сервиса `itrack.ru/whatcms` и запретить определять мой сайт.
Я натравливаю этот ресурс на свой сайт и смотрю логи `access.log` но почему-то след от этого сервиса не могу найти в нём. Прошу помощи определить ip этого сервиса... спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Все просто - ping определяет ip хоста.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: он то определяет, но лучше это делать прямо на хосте. К тому же, они могут проверять сайт с другого хоста.

Comment: Спасибо, но как сказал KoVadim определяет он с другого хоста... я проверил... вставил ip от itrack.ru в файрвол и он все равно проверяет... KoVadim, не знаете как узнать айпишник с какого они определяют?

Comment: я думаю, что это было бы слишком наивно, если бы Вы могли просто взять и закрыть фаерволом один айпи и все сразу заработало. Скорее всего они пользуются каким-нибудь амазоном и придется банить целые подсетки.

Проверяют они достаточно просто - просто наличие/отсутствие определенных url'ов. Но это можно сделать и не подключаясь явно к Вашему сайту. Можно просто в гугл вбить запрос и посмотреть результат.

Если Вам не хочется, что бы другие знали, на чем сделан Ваш сайт - обманите сервис. Разберитесь, какие url оно проверяет и подсуньте фейковые.

Comment: Можно попросить их не сканировать - http://itrack.ru/research/cmsrate/exclude/

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подробное объяснение, KoVadim. Но у меня еще несколько вопросов:
1)есть такой диапазон ip: 122.99. (так он пишется в htaccess)пишу его в isp manager и выходит ошибка.. как его правильно написать?
2) Подскажите пожалуйста как узнать какие url он проверяет?

Comment: опять предложение угадать ошибку на расстоянии?)))  
@KoVadim предложил правильный вариант, напишите на приведенной ссылке отказ от сканирования.

Comment: 2) - смотреть логи апача или что там у Вас. Например, смотреть access_log на наличие 404 ошибки. Также часто открывают просто главную страницу и проверяют, есть ли там надписи вида "Wordpress версии такой то" или что то подобное. Удалять эти строки как то по лицензионному соглашению некрасиво, но немножко модифицировать можно. Главное, что бы визуально было также. Я, к примеру, заменил бы латинницу киррилицей, где буквы похожи (о, е, у, и так далее).

Comment: ))))))) Спасибо за совет! Просто написал на отказ от сканирования. Обещали в течении 2 дней сделать))))